# Using previous JDK version which is not available via SDKMAN but from adoptopenjdk

Tags: java, sdkman

I have the following situation:

```
$ sdk java list
 AdoptOpenJDK  |     | 15.0.1.j9    | adpt    |            | 15.0.1.j9-adpt      
               |     | 15.0.1.hs    | adpt    | installed  | 15.0.1.hs-adpt      
               |     | 14.0.2.j9    | adpt    |            | 14.0.2.j9-adpt      
               |     | 14.0.2.hs    | adpt    |            | 14.0.2.hs-adpt      
               |     | 13.0.2.j9    | adpt    |            | 13.0.2.j9-adpt      
               |     | 13.0.2.hs    | adpt    |            | 13.0.2.hs-adpt      
               |     | 12.0.2.j9    | adpt    |            | 12.0.2.j9-adpt      
               |     | 12.0.2.hs    | adpt    |            | 12.0.2.hs-adpt      
               |     | 11.0.9.j9    | adpt    |            | 11.0.9.j9-adpt      
               | >>> | 11.0.9.hs    | adpt    | installed  | 11.0.9.hs-adpt    
...
```

But on adoptopenjdk the following version https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-binaries/releases/tag/jdk-11.0.8%2B10 is available and can be downloaded.

But when I try to install it via sdkman:

```
$ sdk java install 
tools$ sdk install java 11.0.8.hs-adpt

Stop! java 11.0.8.hs-adpt is not available. Possible causes:
 * 11.0.8.hs-adpt is an invalid version
 * java binaries are incompatible with Darwin
 * java has not been released yet
```

Is there a way to handle that via sdkman or not?

Answer (score 2):

sdkman doesn't recognize as candidates every existing version of the jdk.
However it allows to add local version as compensation.

Thus you'll just have to download the specific version you need, store it in any path you want, and then use a command to register the local version as installed in sdkman:

https://sdkman.io/usage#localversion